# What pronoun to use with verbs that require "de"?

Tags: verbes

I ran into this while trying to use *approcher,* which as far as I know is usually used as *approcher de.*

I was saying "The managers are approaching me."

So I got "Les directeurs m'approchent," but then I wasn't really sure, since it has *de* which made me think of *en* and then I got nervous and decided to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Approcher*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/approcher) can be used both transitively, intransitively, and as a pronominal verb (*s'approcher*). All three possibilities produce a slightly different meaning. I'll give some examples bellow. The translation you provided “*Les directeurs m'approchent*” corresponds to a transitive use of the verb and is probably the best translation for your original sentence—however it may sound less natural in French.

**Pronominal use**:

> Il s'approche de la vérité.
>   Les directeurs s'approchent de moi.

Meaning approximatively:

- He is getting close to the truth. (Actively)
- The managers are coming close to me.

**Intransitive use**:

> Il approche de la vérité.
>   Je voulais empêcher qu'il n'approche de moi.
>   (Les directeurs approchent de moi.)

Approximatively:

- He gets close to the truth. (It happens)
- I wanted to prevent him to get close to me. (I don't want it to happen.)
- The managers get close to me. (It happens)

Remark: The last sentence is inside brackets because it would be hard to find a context in which it is appropriate. Such a phrasing would mean that the managers' intentions are purely irrelevant, they just happen to come close.
(I'm not sure the translation reflects that.)

**Transitively**:

> Il approche le ministre.
>   Les directeurs m'approchent.

Approximatively:

- He is approaching the minister. (That is, he most probably wants to speak.)
- The managers are approaching me.

That's your original sentence. Notice however that, in everyday life, French speakers would almost always use the pronominal form instead to describe a scene, unless there is something inappropriate with someone approaching someone else.

---

Oh, and to make things even more complex, there is another use case for the transitive form:

> Il approche l'enfant de la table.

He brings the child closer to the table.

Comment: Doesn't *approcher qqun* most commonly mean "meet with, talk to [about something]"? ([TLiF's meaning I.A.1.c)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/approcher))? The last meaning feels off too. I'd never use *approcher* there, only *rapprocher*.

Comment: What else would you do with a minister?… As for the last example both are possible, with a slightly different meaning again (my example was adapted from the first example in Wikipédia).

Answer (score 2):

Well. You probably want "les directeurs s'approchent de moi".

"Les directeurs m'approchent" is correct, but has [another meaning](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/approcher), "the managers take contact with me".

Answer (score 0):

You can say “*Les directeurs s'approchent de moi*”, because we say “*s'approcher de quelque chose*” not “*approcher quelque chose*”.

Comment: *Approcher quelqu'un* est tout à fait correct.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Yes, but the meaning is completely different. I'm not sure which meaning is intended by the question.

Comment: @Gilles: Me neither, that why answering this question is so difficult :-)