# « S'approcher » et « s'approcher de »

Tags: grammaire, vocabulaire, choix-de-mot, prépositions

Quand est-ce qu'on utilise "s'approcher + place" et quand est-ce qu'on utilise "s'approcher de + place"? Mon livre de français dit "s'approcher (de)" mais n'explique pas l'usage.

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/3104/what-pronoun-to-use-with-verbs-that-require-de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lorsque la place n'est pas définie, mais qu'il s'agit d'un mouvement pour *venir près*, il n'y a pas de *de* :

> À la guerre approcher est plus important, plus difficile que combattre - Malraux
>
> N'approchez pas ou je tire !
>
> C'est un homme qu'on ne peut approcher.
>
> L'heure approche.
>
> C'est moins bien, mais cela s'en approche

Sinon, on *s'approche de* quelque chose, de quelqu'un, d'un lieu

> Le navire s'approche de la terre
>
> Approchez-vous de la vérité, de la perfection... de moi, du poêle...

*S'approcher [**de** quelqu'un | **de** quelque chose | **du** lieu]* est un *verbe pronominal réfléchi*, il nécessite donc de de définir (par l'article) et de désigner (à l'aide de *de*) ce vers quoi la personne ou l'objet s'approche, et donc, *s'approcher + place* sans *de* ne fonctionne pas.

<sup>Exemples extraits du petit Robert</sup>

Comment: Aussi, quand est-ce que on utilise "de" avec "se souvenir"?

Comment: @RenéG En principe on *se souvient de* quelque chose exprimée dans la phrase ou dans le contexte. Si vous avez des exemples sans *de* il vaut mieux ouvrir une autre question.

Comment: Mais ici tu compares *approcher* avec *s'approcher (de)*, alors que la question porte sur celle entre *s'approcher de (+ lieu)* et *s'approcher (intransitif)*

Comment: *Approcher* est à la fois transitif et intransitif.

Comment: C'est vrai. Et le verbe *chanter* aussi. Je me permettais de faire remarquer que la question ne porte **pas** sur le verbe *approcher*.

Comment: @RomainVALERI En effet, mais comme je l'ai ajouté à la fin de ma réponse *s'approcher (de)* n'est pas intransitif... enfin c'est ce que j'ai pu comprendre.

Comment: Il semble que vous n'ayez pas abordé la question.

Comment: @Arun J'ai augmenté le dernier paragraphe de ma réponse pour répondre à : *Mon livre de français dit "s'approcher (de)" mais n'explique pas l'usage.*

Answer (score 4):

Contrairement à ce qu'il me semble lire dans ta question, on ne dit **pas** "s'approcher + place".

Il y a une distinction, oui, entre :

- **s'approcher de + (lieu)**

et

- **s'approcher** (sans complément de lieu explicite)

Cette deuxième variante n'est qu'une manière d'alléger l'expression quand le contexte permet de comprendre implicitement le lieu dont le sujet approche.

Exemple :

> Je recule au fur et à mesure qu'il s'approche. *(ici, on comprend que c'est de moi qu'il s'approche)*

mais la forme

> Je recule au fur et à mesure qu'il s'approche **de moi**.

serait bien évidemment correcte aussi.

Comment: On reste dans l'ambiguïté de la question : "... *de moi*" n'est pas égal à *+ place*.

Comment: @cl-r C'est juste, mais en l'occurrence la phrase n'est pas là en exemple de la forme *+ place*, je précisais que la partie implicite de mon exemple pouvait être explicite également.